# Good method for saving and inserting commonly used snippets

Tags: cut-copy-paste, snippets

I often need to insert the same text into a file.

My approach has been to put the text into my vimrc as a variable:

```
let map='<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">'
```

And then insert it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, =map <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This *works* but it somehow feels wrong. It also prevents me from entering long, multiline snippets. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** I'm open to a solution that uses a plugin, but I'm using an older version of Vim that's missing python and a few other features. I'd prefer a simple solution.

Comment: What about a snippet plugin like [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) or [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)?

Comment: @statox, I haven't found a snippet plugin that I like (e.g. something lightweight and simple). I'm also using an ancient version of Vim that wasn't compiled with python, so utlisnips is out.

Comment: Y don't you try something like mapping or abbreviations?

Comment: [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/) may not be simple as it requires other plugins and it has many features, however, it doesn't require Python.

Answer (score 4):

I came across a solution that suits me well, it may be useful for you also. I add some mappings/abbreviations in insert mode starting with `\` (or any character you like, and use not all the time):

```
" use an abbreviation (css debugging)
iabbrev \r *{color: red !important;}

" use a mapping (html doctype insertion)
inoremap \doctype <!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">

" if you want to keep cursor inside tag, use a mapping also
inoremap \td   <td></td><left><left><left><left><left>
" some more mappings

" if you used a mapping starting with \ make sure you can actually type \
inoremap \\ \
```

The major down point of this is that the mappings you define can overlap other actual words you may want to use, but on the other side you can create a lot of mappings without use of any external plugin.

I noticed that mapping are not displayed while typed, but you can display them with `:set showcmd` (thanks to a [jair lopez](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/6698/jair-lopez) comment)

Comment: It's basically the same thing to what Nobe4 has but you could also consider using `iabbrev`. see `:help abbrev`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change the cursor position with an abbreviation though...

Comment: True, but Scribblemacher didn't specifically say he needed to move cursor position did he? It all just depends on what he needs. I was just giving options. :)

Comment: Right, I'll add your idea for the first one

Comment: With `:set showcmd` you can see a mapping as you type it, in the last line of the screen. See [`:help 'showcmd'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27) for more information.